# SwiftUI TabView & tabViewStyle(.page) $selection Fails

Tags: swiftui, tvos, swiftui-tabview

Starting in tvOS 17.2 I've encountered some strange behavior with TabView automatically setting the $selection back to the first tab.

For example, the following code should load on the 5th tab. It initially does, but then scrolls all the way to the first tab automatically once the view appears.

```
import SwiftUI

@available(tvOS 17.2, *)
struct TestTabView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedTabIndex = 5 // Pre select tab 5
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTabIndex) {
            ForEach(1...20, id: \.self) { i in
                Text("Tab: \(i)")
                    .tag(i)
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page)
    }
}
```

This has only recently become an issue starting with 17.2. If you run the same code on tvOS 16.* or 17.0 it works correctly. The code also works correctly in Previews but doesn't in the simulator or on a real device.

I think I've narrowed it down to an issue with *.tabViewStyle(.page)*. The same code for a normal tab view works correctly:

```
@available(tvOS 17.2, *)
struct TestTabView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedTabIndex: Int = 3
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTabIndex) {
            ForEach(1...20, id: \.self) { i in
                Text("Tab: \(i)")
                    .tag(i)
                    .tabItem { Text("\(i)") } // <-- ADDED
            }
        }
        // <-- REMOVED .tabViewStyle(.page)
    }
}
```

What can I do to fix this? Even a work around would be great. This issue completely breaks my app. I have TabView with 100-200 tabs and always need to load on a specific tab.